# Magento website down after installing an extension

Tags: magento

My website went down after I tried to install this a blog extension : 
composer require magefan/module-blog

I tried to do 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

But nothing works i got 500 error please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give permission to your var and pub/static folder.
chmod -R 777 var pub/static

It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps:-

1. Delete all folders under pub/static
2. Delete var/cache
3. Delete var/composer_home
4. Delete var/generation
5. Delete var/page_cache
6. Delete var/view_preprocessed
7. Give permission to your var and pub/static folder. chmod -R 777 var pub/static

Now open your command prompt and go to your root installation of Magento 2 and run the following commands

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

**Note:** If you removed the .htaccess file you could have lots of problems. (getting 404 errors when trying to access your CSS + javascript files and whatnot.

If this is happening to you the best way I found of fixing this is re-downloading the Magento zip or tar and extracting the pub/static folder to your project directory. This should include the .htaccess file and fix any problem you have.